# value not recognized in php

Tags: php

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$i=0;
while(i<4){ ?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_'.$i; ?>"/>
<?php
}

?>
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit"/>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
 {

    $i=0;
    while($i<4)
    {
        echo $i;
        $chek=$_POST['chkApprove_'.$i];// Error Undefined Index

        $i++;
    }
 }
```

Error is displayed as Undefined index: chkApprove_0...chkApprove_3. Am i doing something wrong here.

Comment: How is this even loading? infinite loop!

Comment: If the checkbox isn't checked it will not be submitted.

Comment: Infinite loop and you forgot the $ sign too

Comment: @DamienPirsy you should have posted this as answer quickest to answer... +1 for u

Comment: and `<?php` too :) toooo much errors for such a little piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

$ was missing in you while loop before "i". and $i was not increamenting.

```
<?php
$i=0;
while($i<4){ ?> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_'.$i; ?>"/>
<?php
     $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: copy the above code and paste. and 1 thing to remember , the checkbox will be checked when you are submitting. and put some value in the value attribute in checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

try this : you start from `$i=0` but not increment `$i++`.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($i < 4)
    { 
?> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_'.$i; ?>"/>
<?php
    $i++;
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
    $i=0;
    while($i < 4) {
        echo $i;
        $chek=$_POST['chkApprove_'.$i];// Error Undefined Index
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have a syntax error and you forget to increment $i in this loop:

```
    $i=0;
while(i<4){ ?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_'.$i; ?>"/>
<?php
}
```

should be

```
   $i=0;
while($i<4){ ?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_'.$i; ?>"/>
<?php
$i++;
}
```

Because you don't increment $i in the intial loop, but in the latter looop you do, you get the undefined index

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
$i=0;
while($i<4){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'chkApprove_' . $i; ?>"/>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 4) {
        echo $i;
        $chek = $_POST['chkApprove_' . $i];
        // Error Undefined Index

        $i++;
    }
}
```